# GitLab Markdown: Including markdown in projects homepage

Tags: markdown, gitlab

I've recently started using GitLab and really like the support for README.md.  However, in my opinion, the markdown shows up in the wrong place.  I would be nice to see that information up front as an introduction to the project, especially if the markdown is kept up to date with the project’s current status.

Is there any way to make markdown show up on the project’s homepage (ie, the Activities tab) instead of the Files tab?

(Using GitLab 7.2.2)

Answer (score 0):

What you ask has been declined and partially implemented with cookies at: http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/3907476-add-readme-to-project-home-view (I also wish it were possible...)

Please always look up on the feature request forum http://feedback.gitlab.com before asking if GitLab has a feature here: it has often already been requested.